# invalid argument: No host specified in URI /data/user/0/com.example.projectdesign_app/cache

Tags: android, flutter, dart

how to acces this link to use the image i just upload, i try to save image by upload image by camera or choose by gallery,

```
Wrap(children:<Widget> [
                ElevatedButton(
                //call image painter here
                onPressed: ()async{
                   Navigator.push(
                      context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ImagePainterExample(image: _image,)),
               );
                }, 
                child: const Text ('Paint Image'),),
                ElevatedButton(
               onPressed:  ()async {
               // call dialog and get value "camera" or "galery"
               final type = await  _settingModalBottomSheet(context);
               if(type != null){
               // call image pikcer
              final pickedFile = await _openImagePicker(type);
                if(pickedFile !=null){ 
                   // set here
                   setState(()
                     {_image = pickedFile;});
                 }
                }
              },
               child: const Text('Select An Image'),
               ),
               ElevatedButton(onPressed: () async {
                if(_image!=null){
                final path = _image!.path;
                final tempDir = await getExternalStorageDirectory();
                final jln = '${tempDir!.path}/myfile.jpg';
                await Dio().download(path,jln);
                await GallerySaver.saveImage(path, toDcim: true); }
                else{
                return;
                  }
               },
               
               child: const Text('Save Image'),

               ),
              ],
```

i want save or paint the image i upload to app but i get this error with no host url, i keep finding the solution but in url, cant you use image from cache app itself?

```
Future<File?> _openImagePicker(String pickerType) async { 
  XFile? pickedImage ;
  switch (pickerType) {
   case "gallery":
     /// GALLERY IMAGE PICKER
      pickedImage  = await _picker.pickImage(
          source: ImageSource.gallery);
        break;
      case "camera": // CAMERA CAPTURE CODE
        pickedImage  = await _picker.pickImage(
            source: ImageSource.camera);
        break;
    }
    if (pickedImage != null) {
      debugPrint("SELECTED IMAGE PICK   $pickedImage");
      final  tempImg = File(pickedImage.path);
       return tempImg; 
    } else
    {
      print("You have not taken image");
    }
```